# Why can two `Session`s created over the same `Engine` see each others uncommitted changes, when using isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`?

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

Why can two `Session`s created over the same `Engine` see each others uncommitted changes, when using isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`?

How can the query `print(s2.query(User).filter(User.name == 'bob').all())` retrieve the `User` "bob", when this user was flushed to the database by the query `print(s1.query(User).filter(User.name == 'alice').all())` (`autoflush=True`) and not committed yet?

I first assumed that the issue was caused by SQLite using an isolation level of `READ_UNCOMITTED` by default, until I explicitly set the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` and experienced the same result.

Can anyone explain?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session, relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    age = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))

    team = relationship('Team', back_populates='users')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{}(id={},name={})>'.format(__class__.__name__, self.id, self.name)

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

    users = relationship('User', back_populates='team')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{}(id={},name={})>'.format(__class__.__name__, self.id, self.name)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', isolation_level='SERIALIZABLE', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)

s1 = Session()
s2 = Session()

user1 = User(name='alice', age=20)
user2 = User(name='bob', age=30)

team1 = Team(name='pirates')
team1.users = [user1, user2]

s1.add(team1)

print(s1.query(User).filter(User.name == 'alice').all())
print(s2.query(User).filter(User.name == 'bob').all())
```

Comment: See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior

Comment: @IljaEverilä - Will you elaborate? What specific are you trying to tell me from that documentation on dialects? I know dialects are used to talk to DPAPI.

Comment: From "When a `:memory:` SQLite database is specified, the dialect by default will use `SingletonThreadPool`" onwards, though the entire linked section about threading behaviour is a good read. The thing about in-memory SQLite databases is that they only exist within the scope of their connection.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - So, "*... This pool maintains a single connection per thread, so that all access to the engine within the current thread use the same :memory: database - other threads would access a different :memory: database.*", effectively means that all sessions use the exact same connection, and therefore can see each other's `flush()`'ed data before `commit()`? In a normal scenario, each session would use a separate connection from the connection pool, so that they would not be able to see each other's `flush()`'ed data, right?

Comment: Precisely. This is an "artefact" of using SQLite in-memory database.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - I thank you.